# Fisher Information Matrix singular but unbiased estimator exists? Please help me figure out where I've gone wrong

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

I'm doing some research into the Cramer-Rao bound for time of arrival localization and have come across a rather strange result: the FIM is singular, but there exists an unbiased estimator. My supervisor insists I'm wrong (I'm sure I must be), but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help guide me in the right direction? Sorry for the long development of the problem below.

---

A transmitter T is at an unknown location $\theta=(x, y)^{T}$. There are $s$ sensors in the region $\Omega$. The $j^{th}$ sensor positioned at $\theta_{j}=(x_{j}, y_{j})^{T}$ measures a distance/range to T that is a random variable dependent on the actual distance of T from the sensor ($d_{j}$).

The measurement vector for all anchors is therefore:
\begin{align}
        r=[d_{1}+\epsilon_{1},...,d_{j}+\epsilon_{j}]^{T}=d(\theta)+\epsilon=\|\theta-\theta_{j}\|_{_{2}} + \epsilon
\end{align}

where the error is assumed to be normally distributed $\epsilon \sim N\left(0, \Sigma_{s_{\mathrm{x}}s}\right)$.

For a multivariate Gaussian distribution, the $(m,n)$ element of the FIM is:

\begin{align}
FIM_{m,n}=\frac{\partial d^{T}}{\partial \theta_m} \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial d}{\partial \theta_n}+\frac{1}{2} TR\left(\Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial \theta_m} \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial \theta_n}\right)
\end{align}

Assuming independent noise at the sensor measurement and a constant variance for the noise at each sensor, the covariance matrix is diagonal, i.e. $\Sigma=diag(\sigma^{2}_{1}, \sigma^{2}_{2},..., \sigma^{2}_{s})$. Thus, the FIM can be expanded for $\theta=(x, y)^{T}$ as:

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
FIM_{1,1} & FIM_{1,2} \\
FIM_{2,1} & FIM_{2,2}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
\label{FIM11}
FIM_{1,1}
&=
\sum_{j=1}^{s} \frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{-2}\left(\frac{\partial \sigma_{j}^{2}}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{\partial d_{j}}{\partial x}\right)^{2}\\
&=
\sum_{j=1}^{s} \left(\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{-1}cos^{2}(\phi_j)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\label{FIM12}
FIM_{1,2}=FIM_{2,1}&=\sum_{j=1}^{s} \frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{-2} \frac{\partial \sigma_{j}^{2}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \sigma_{j}^{2}}{\partial y}+\left(\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{-1} \frac{\partial d_{j}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial d_{j}}{\partial y}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{s} \left(\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{-1} cos(\phi_j) sin(\phi_j)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\label{FIM22}
FIM_{2,2}
&=
\sum_{j=1}^{s} \frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{-2}\left(\frac{\partial \sigma_{j}^{2}}{\partial y}\right)^{2}+\left(\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{\partial d_{j}}{\partial y}\right)^{2}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{s} \left(\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{-1}sin(\phi_j)^{2}
\end{align}

Where $\phi_j$ is the angle between the $j^{th}$ sensor and T.

Consider 3 sensors situated at (-1,0),(0,0) and (1,0), and T at (2,0). The FIM is clearly singular as $\phi_j=0 \forall j$ and so the CRB does not exist.

The circles for two different range measurements are shown, and overlayed with the negative log-likelihood (NLL) function for the measurement. When 2 or more circles intersect, they do so at 2 locations which have reflection symmetry along the y=0 line, and so the NLL function has a minima at these two points. When no circles intersect, the NLL function has a minima on the y=0 line. Therefore, the y-coordinate MLE (i.e. estimator that minimizes NLL function) is unbiased and has finite variance.

[image: Range circles & NLL function]

This is the output of 1500 MLE estimates I computed in a simulation:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out where I've gone wrong.

Comment: I don't quite see how you've proven that the $y$-variance of the MLE is finite. I think the data looks pretty consistent: notice already in your simulation that the $x$-spread is much smaller than the $y$-spread. I'd suspect that a) if you inscrease the number of MLEs, $N,$ then $y$ spread increases (much faster than the $\sqrt{N\log N }$ scale you'd expect from just a noisy finite variance sample), and b) as you increase the number of samples $n$, the $x$-spread shrinks and the $y$-spread remains roughly constant (certainly not decaying like $1/\sqrt{n}$). Try these?

Comment: Oh, and to contextualise, it might be worth seeing what a finite sample from a density without a second moment looks like (especially as the number of samples increases). Try sampling from Cauchy-like laws, and see if the scatter plots you get are similar to your case.

Comment: Given a finite noise variance for the three measured ranges, the circles will never intersect at infinity when T is at (2,0), so the NLL will never have minima at infinity. Thus, the MLE will never produce estimates at infinity. So how could the MLE variance be non-finite? In fact, when I used a small ranging noise variance, the circles intersect not too far from the actual paramater value (as in the figure - notice the points become fewer at the fringes). Even when the circles do not intersect, the NLL function has a minima on the y=0 line. I don't see how the y-variance can be infinity.

Comment: And certainly increasing the number of simulations from 1,000 to 25,000 that I've tried has not increased the variance. I really can't understand where I'm going wrong.
(EDIT: I should mention that I'm an engineer, not a mathematician, my supervisor is a mathematician, but aside from pretty forcefully saying I'm wrong, he hasn't pointed out how or why)

Comment: Note that you can be almost surely finite but have unbounded variance. The Cauchy density is an example (in fact, an extreme example, since it doesn't even have a well-defined mean). 

Anyway,  I ran a few simple simulations myself, and it appears that the variance of the estimate $\mathrm{var}(\hat{y})$ scales more like $n^{-1/4}$ rather than $n^{-1/2},$ where $n$ is the number of samples used to construct the estimate. My natural guess is that you can do an analysis that first argues that the law of the observation under $(2,0)$ and under $(2, \varepsilon)$ is essentially the same (contd)

Comment: (where $\varepsilon$ will depend on $n$), and then use the nonzero $\varepsilon$ to come up with variance bounds that are somewhat more benign. The overall structure may be that while there is a small chance of getting the estimate very wrong indeed, in the bulk of cases the estimate is okay, but just converges at a slow rate. Also, I'd suggest asking your supervisor to explain (figuring out how to do these things is of course important for your working life). In any case, I can certainly say that I don't see anything wrong with your calculation of the Fisher information here.